# Losing IPv6 route or connectivity on bonded interface 16.04LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, ipv6, network-bonding

Good afternoon, all. Running 16.04LTS on a SuperMicro X7DBN motherboard. I have two possibly related problems that I will describe separately.

First, I seem to be losing IPv6 connectivity 5-10 minutes after booting.  Below is the contents of my /etc/network/interfaces file

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address 172.16.1.100
        gateway 172.16.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        dns-search home.example.com
        dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
        bond-mode 4
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-lacp-rate 1
        bond-slaves enp4s0f0 enp4s0f1

iface bond0 inet6 static
        address 2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::a
        netmask 64
        gateway fe80::1
        dns-search home.example.com
        dns-nameservers ::1
```

I can ping6 the gateway:

```
user@monstro:/etc/network/interfaces.d$ ping6 fe80::1 -I bond0
PING fe80::1(fe80::1) from fe80::230:48ff:fec6:fa2 bond0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.507 ms
64 bytes from fe80::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.459 ms
```

I can ping6 the actual address of the gateway:

```
user@monstro:/etc/network/interfaces.d$ ping6 2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::1
PING 2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::1(2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=105 ms
64 bytes from 2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.531 ms
```

I cannot ping6 anything outside of the gateway. Routing information:

```
user@monstro:/etc/network/interfaces.d$ route -6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::/64       ::                         UA   256 2    38 bond0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 2     3 bond0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   833 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   8    48 lo
2605:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::a/128     ::                         Un   0   2   398 lo
fe80::230:48ff:fec6:fa2/128    ::                         Un   0   2    88 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 7    62 bond0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   833 lo
```

I mentioned two problems. The second one is, I have to reboot every time I make changes to the interfaces file. I am unable do restart networking in order to restart networking. The interface bond0 will not respond. Here is what it looks like:

```
user@monstro:/etc/network/interfaces.d$ sudo systemctl restart networking
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
user@monstro:/etc/network/interfaces.d$ journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit networking.service has begun starting up.
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro ifup[4164]: sh: echo: I/O error
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro kernel: bond0: Setting MII monitoring interval to 100
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro kernel: bond0: option mode: unable to set because the bo
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro ifup[4164]: sh: echo: I/O error
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro ifup[4164]: Waiting for a slave to join bond0 (will time
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro kernel: bond0: option lacp_rate: unable to set because t
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro ifup[4164]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro ifup[4164]: Failed to bring up bond0.
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, cod
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro sudo[4156]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for u
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed stat
Jun 21 13:37:23 monstro systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit
lines 2550-2572/2572 (END)
```

I do not know if these two issues are related, or if I need to deal with them separately.  Anyone?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it was simple. I had to add the following to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
```

This wasn't necessary in previous versions that I have run, but now it is.  At least, for my particular setup it is...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is NOT the answer, as I still seem to lose my ipv6 route after about half an hour of a reboot. Has anyone else run into this issue?